# How to differentiate received MMS messages in Android?

Tags: android

Can any body Help me about How to differentiate received MMS messages in Android? Because I am getting wrong total for received MMS in android? I have used following code for getting count.

```
   Uri mmsInboxUri = Uri.parse("content://mms");                
   Cursor mmsInboxCursor = getContentResolver().query(mmsInboxUri ,new String[]
   {"_id","msg_box","ct_t"}, "msg_box=1 or msg_box=2", null, null);
   int count = mmsInboxCursor.getCount();
```